# yii html2pdf keep css formatting

Tags: php, yii, html-table, wkhtmltopdf, html2pdf

I am trying to create a PDF file using html2pdf. I have followed this [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf). I can create it in html fine and everything is in printable area however the created PDF does not display same results. the table width are not kept. Data is cut off at end of page on right side.

In controller

```
$html2pdf = Yii::app()->ePdf->HTML2PDF('L',"A4","en", array(10, 10, 10, 10));
        $html2pdf->WriteHTML($print);
        $html2pdf->Output();
```

page to be created

```
<style type="text/css">

    @media print{thead{display:table-header-group; margin-bottom:2px;}}
    @page{margin-top:1cm;margin-left:1cm;margin-right:1cm;margin-bottom:1.5cm;}}

.odd {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E5F1F4;
}
.even {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
}
table tbody tr:hover{
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 lightgreen;
}
table tbody tr{
    font-size:10pt;
}
body
{
  margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;
}

.grey{
    background: lightgrey;
}

.center{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.size{
    font-size:15px;
}

table{
    padding-botton:30px;
}

</style>

<body onload="window.print();window.close();">
<h1 class="grey center">Project Report</h1>
<?php 
$count = 0;
$class= null;
foreach($results as $key=>$data) {
?>
<table width=0>
<tr class="grey size">
    <th colspan=12><?=$key ?></th>
</tr>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Actual End Date</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>%</th>
        <th>% Planned</th>
        <th>KM</th>
        <th>KM Planned</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th width="150">AREA</th>
        <th>PROJ INFO</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($data as $column=>$q) {   ?>

    <?php 
        $class = ($count % 2 === 0) ? 'odd' : 'even';
        $this->renderPartial('_report',array('data'=>$q,'class'=>$class));
        $count++;
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>

<?php }
?>

</body>
```

_report.php

```
<tr class=<?=$class?>>
    <td><?php //$startdate = 
    echo CHtml::encode($data['StartDATE']);
            /*$createstartdate = new DateTime($startdate);
            $strip = $createstartdate->format(Yii::app()->params['companies'][Yii::app()->params['currentLocation']]['dateFormat']);
            echo($strip);
            $strip = null;*/
        ?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::encode($data['PROJECT']);?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::encode($data['PROJCODE']); echo CHtml::encode($data['PROJID']);?></td>
    <td><?php //$enddate = 
    echo CHtml::encode($data['ActualEndDate']);
        /*$createenddate = new DateTime($enddate);
        $strip = $createenddate->format(Yii::app()->params['companies'][Yii::app()->params['currentLocation']]['dateFormat']);
        echo($strip);
        $strip = null;*/        
        ?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::encode($data['OFFICE']);?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::encode($data['PERCENT']);?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::encode($data['PERCENTPlanned']);?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::encode($data['KM']);?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::encode($data['KMPlanned']);?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::encode($data['COUNTRY']);?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::encode($data['AREA']);?></td>
    <td><?php echo CHtml::encode($data['PROJINFO']);?></td> 
</tr>
```

Using pdfable I get following error:

```
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/CController.php(783): CController->renderPartial('<style type="te...', Array, true)
#1 /opt/paradox/protected/extensions/pdfable/PdfFile.php(131): CController->render('<style type="te...', Array, true)
#2 /opt/paradox/protected/extensions/pdfable/PdfFile.php(86): PdfFile->render('<style type="te...', Array)
#3 /opt/paradox/protected/extensions/pdfable/Pdfable.php(205): PdfFile->renderPage('<style type="te...', Array, Array)
#4 [internal function]: Pdfable->renderPdf('<style type="te...')
#5 /opt/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/base/CComponent.php(261): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 [internal function]: CComponent->__call('renderPdf', Array)
#7 /opt/paradox/protected/controllers/ViewWebprojectreportController.php(297): ViewWebprojectreportController->renderPdf('<style type="te...')
#8 /opt/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(50): ViewWebprojectreportController->actionPrint()
#9 /opt/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/CController.php(309): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#10 /opt/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/filters/CFilterChain.php(134): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#11 /opt/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/CController.php(292): CFilterChain->run()
#12 /opt/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/CController.php(266): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#13 /opt/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(283): CController->run('print')
#14 /opt/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(142): CWebApplication->runController('ViewWebprojectr...')
#15 /opt/yii-1.1.12.b600af/framework/base/CApplication.php(162): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#16 /opt/paradox/index.php(13): CApplication->run()
#17 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/paradox/index.php?r=ViewWebprojectreport/print
HTTP_REFERER=http://portal-test/paradox/index.php?r=ViewWebprojectreport/admin
```

after updating to `$this->renderPdf('print',array('results'=>$results));` i get new error

```
2013/06/05 12:11:33 [error] [ext.pdfable.Pdfable] Could not create PDF for view print
in /opt/paradox/protected/extensions/pdfable/Pdfable.php (209)
in /opt/paradox/protected/controllers/ViewWebprojectreportController.php (297)
in /opt/paradox/index.php (13)
```

**via mpdf**

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 258180 bytes) in /opt/paradox/protected/vendors/MPDF56/mpdf.php on line 10125, referer: http‌://portal-test/paradox/index.php?r=ViewWebprojectreport/admin

I pasted the styling in the variable `$stylesheet`

Comment: It seems you render a HTML document without a starting `<html>` tag. That's why you get the error from the pdfable extension. Actually there should be another error message over the stack trace which would also be useful.

Answer (score 4):

html2pdf is perfect extension and I working on it in perfect way .

To solve your problem you have to add your css in external file .

foe example :

```
$mpdf=Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf('utf-8', 'Letter-L');
$mpdf->ignore_invalid_utf8 = true;
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('certificate.css'); /// here call you external css file 

$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);/// here your content



$mpdf->Output("myfile.pdf", 'D');


exit;
```

this example from my project it's work in perfect way  with all css fetchers :

```
   $html= '   
<body>

<div class="wi">
        <p align="center" dir="LTR">
        </p>
        <p align="center" dir="LTR">
        <img src="illaf.jpg" width="10.23cm" height="2.36cm" /></p>
        <p align="center" dir="LTR">

            <div class="herby">
            Hereby certifies that
            </div>

            </p>
        <p align="center" dir="LTR">
            </p>
        <p align="center" >
            <div class='.$style.'>
           '.$name.'  '.$father.'  '.$last_name.'
            </div>
            </p>
        <p align="center" dir="LTR">
            Has completed training program which was conducted according to the standards and guidelines<br/> established by XXXXX<sup>&reg;</sup>. The holder of this certificate has been trained by a registered XXXXX<sup>&reg;</sup><br /> Trainer and has achieved the standards required to merit this certificate.</p>
        <p align="center" dir="LTR">
            </p>
        <p align="center" dir="LTR">
            ILLAFTrain<sup>&reg;</sup> has therefore conferred upon the holder this certificate in</p>
        <p align="center" dir="LTR">
            <div class="trainer_type">
        '.$course_name.'
            </div>
            </p>
            </br>
               </br>
                  </br>
            <div calss="marginbutton">
        <table  align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="ltr">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:643px;">
                        <p dir="LTR">
                        </p>
                        <p dir="LTR">
                            </p>
                        <p dir="LTR">

                    </td>
                    <td style="width:267px;">
                        <p dir="LTR">
                            </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                        <p dir="LTR">
                            <td>

                            The following have officially decreed their signatures<br/>
                            hereon on this '.$day.'<sup>th</sup>day of '.$month.' in the year '.$year.'</p>
            </td>


                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:643px;">
                        <p dir="LTR">
                            </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:267px;">
                        <p align="center" dir="LTR" style="margin-left:2.25pt;">
                            </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td >
                        <p dir="LTR">
                            </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>


                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td >
                    </br>
                    </br>
                     </br>
                      </br>



                    </td>
                    <td >


                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </br>
        </br>
        </br>

         <table>
<tr>
    <td>                   <div class="pdraa" >
                                 Trainer:
    '.$trainer.' ____________  

          </div></td>
    <td>
               <div class="pdraa" >

    '.$trainers[0].' 

          </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
               <div class="pdraa" >

    '.$trainers[1].' 

          </div>

    </td>
    <td>
               <div class="pdraa" >

        '.$trainers[2].' 
          </div>

    </td>
</tr>
</table>

    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
         <div class="number">

                            <strong>'.$cirt_id.'</strong>

                             </div> 

        <div class="site">
                                    www.<strong>XXXX</strong>.co.uk
                                     </div> 
        <div style="clear:both;">
            </div>


            </div>
            </body>

    ';
$mpdf=Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf('utf-8', 'Letter-L');
$mpdf->ignore_invalid_utf8 = true;
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('certificate.css'); /// here call you external css file 

$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);



$mpdf->Output("$name$user_id$last_name.pdf", 'D');


exit;
```

Comment: Try to add all your function to controller not in view and will work .